# Powershell: How remove CRLF from lines that do not meet criteria in text file

Tags: powershell

This seems simple enough but cannot get anything I try to work. I am trying to remove the CRLF from the ends of lines that don't meet my criteria, then output the file to an new file. For example this section:

```
One~Two~Three~Four
Test Plan Pay Work~scheduled payment pending~79f1cf6e~3/8/2020 6:13:07 PM
Test Plan Pay Work~Bad Request~680a0bb2~3/8/2020 6:14:00 AM
Test Plan Pay Work~GetCardInfo 
{failed to validate card
}
~f124a822-aa8d-4624-bb8c-ddsfgdfcc21fb~3/8/2020 6:14:31 PM
Test Plan Pay Work~Bad Request~680a0bb2~3/8/2020 6:14:00 AM
```

Should output to look like:

```
One~Two~Three~Four
Test Plan Pay Work~scheduled payment pending~79f1cf6e~3/8/2020 6:13:07 PM
Test Plan Pay Work~Bad Request~680a0bb2~3/8/2020 6:14:00 AM
Test Plan Pay Work~GetCardInfo {failed to validate card}~f124a822~3/8/2020 6:14:31 PM
Test Plan Pay Work~Bad Request~680a0bb2~3/8/2020 6:14:00 AM
```

Being a newbie I have tried:

```
Get-Content "C:\temp\errors.csv" | ForEach-Object {
  if ((!$_.EndsWith("AM") -and !$_.EndsWith("PM") -and !$_.EndsWith("Four")))
    {
       $_ -replace ("`r`n",' ')
    }
} | Out-File C:\temp\errors2.csv
```

But this does not work. Any ideas on this? Seems simple but cannot get it to work whatever I try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Get-Content` splits text into separate lines and removes the newline characters by default. To prevent that use parameter `-Raw`. Now you can process the text as a whole, using regular expression [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.1#replacement-operator) operator:

```
(Get-Content 'errors.csv' -Raw) -replace '(?<!AM|PM|Four)\r\n', ' ' | 
    Out-File 'errors2.csv'
```

The parentheses around the `Get-Content` call allow the use of the output of the command directly as the left-hand side operand of the `-replace` operator (see [Grouping Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators?view=powershell-7.1#grouping-operator--)).

**Output:**

```text
One~Two~Three~Four
Test Plan Pay Work~scheduled payment pending~79f1cf6e~3/8/2020 6:13:07 PM
Test Plan Pay Work~Bad Request~680a0bb2~3/8/2020 6:14:00 AM
Test Plan Pay Work~GetCardInfo  {failed to validate card } ~f124a822-aa8d-4624-bb8c-ddsfgdfcc21fb~3/8/2020 6:14:31 PM
Test Plan Pay Work~Bad Request~680a0bb2~3/8/2020 6:14:00 AM
```

**Regular expression breakdown:**

- `(?<!` starts a negative lookbehind assertion

  - `AM|PM|Four` any of literal `AM`, `PM` or `Four`
- `)` ends the negative lookbehind assertion
- `\r\n` linefeed characters

The negative lookbehind assertion makes the RegEx match only if the linefeed characters are not preceeded by `AM`, `PM` or `Four`. The negative lookbehind doesn't take part of the match result, so only the linefeed characters will be replaced.

[Regex lookahead, lookbehind and atomic groups](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2973436/7571258)

**Note:**

This approach, using `Get-Content -Raw` loads **the entire file** into memory. If the file is too big an approach using default `Get-Content`, to process input line by line (possibly in chunks using parameter `-ReadCount`) would be feasible, but a bit more complicated.